# Adding an arrow to the graph of a function

Tags: graphics, plot, function

I'm making a thermodynamics PV graph to show how a cycle progresses and ideally I'd need to add arrows going along the blue line going left, the red going right and the green going up. But I cannot, for the life of me, find anywhere that shows that it's possible to do this.

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$V$,
    ylabel=$P$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3.5e5, % Changed to 3.5e5 to include the third function properly
    xmin=19,
    xmax=41,
    grid=both,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    width=10cm,
    height=6cm,
]

\addplot[blue, domain=20:40, samples=100] {4011230/x};
\addlegendentry{$P_1 = \frac{4011230}{V_1}$};

\addplot[red, domain=20:40, samples=100] {29768029/(x^1.67)}; % Corrected the power notation
\addlegendentry{$P_2 = \frac{29768029}{V_2^{1.67}}$};

\addplot[green] coordinates {(40,62850) (40,100000)};
\addlegendentry{$V_3 = 40$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
arr/.style={decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{Stealth}},
mark=at position 0.50 with {\arrow{Stealth}},
mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{Stealth}},
},postaction={decorate}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm, height=6cm,
xmin=19, xmax=41,
ymin=0, ymax=3.5e5,
xlabel=$V$, ylabel=$P$,
grid=both,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot[blue, arr, domain=40:20, samples=100] {4011230/x};
\addlegendentry{$P_1=\nicefrac{4011230}{V}$};
\addplot[red, arr, domain=20:40, samples=100] {29768029/(x^1.67)};
\addlegendentry{$P_2=\nicefrac{29768029}{V^{1.67}}$};
\addplot[green, -Stealth] coordinates {(40,{29768029/(40^1.67)}) (40,4011230/40)};
\addlegendentry{$V=40$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: PV diagram with curves with arrows]